# Invalid input syntax [postgre]

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

So, I'm trying to update the database through Knex.JS with the following query

```
breakMinutes: await knex('accounts')
   .select('defaultBreakMinutes')
   .where('id', sourceAccountId)
```

However, when i try to do the operation that will run the query along with others, I get this:

```
some other part......returning * - 
invalid input syntax for integer: "{"{\"defaultBreakMinutes\":45}"}"
```

I tried putting `sourceAccountId` in a parseInt, didn't help though. Any ideeas ?

Comment: If you post more of your code, would be easier for us to help you, like more code from where the query is being made.

Comment: Are calling this function directly or thought an API?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `.select('defaultBreakMinutes')` with `.pluck('defaultBreakMinutes')`.

[Pluck](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-pluck) is the version of `select`, but the difference is that `select` returns an array of objects, but `pluck` picks selected columns and returns them as an array of plain values (not objects).